# In Python/Selenium, How to crawl whole youtube comment?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, youtube, web-crawler

I want to analyze correlation with YouTube comment and Country by using 
Python/selenium

If YouTube's movie contain too many comments, We scroll chrome to search next comment. Therefore I stop 3 seconds until loading comments.

```
last_page_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(3.0)
    new_page_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    if new_page_height == last_page_height:
        break
    last_page_height = new_page_height

html_source = driver.page_source
driver.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'lxml')
```

but this code doesn't crawl whole comments, just about 1500 comments.

Comment: you need to download all `comments` from selected page?

Comment: @Code_Stranding There can be 100/1000 comments, the solution will a bit depend on the number of comments you are dealing with.

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Yes I need to download alll comments

Comment: @DebanjanB I am going to crawl youtube page of BTS that has around 500,000 comments. my code's problem crawl 1500 comments from 500,00 comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube has limit of 1500 comments per quota. It is possible to get more results by usage of Api like : [Youtube Data Api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota%C2%A0)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try to study YouTube Api soon.